# Grub dual boot: Mint update removed grubentry for windows

Tags: boot, grub, linux-mint

I have a problem where Mint updated my system,and also changed my grub2 entries. It needed to do this.. but in changing grub entries it REMOVED my Windows on `/dev/sda1` entry.

I can still see the partition being present if I check with "disks" tool from the menu but I cannot get the vital information of the UUID. Now I cannot even attempt to add a new windows entry in grub.

Any tips?
I tried `blkid`, which does not give me sda1 info.
I tried `vol_id` but not present on mint

I figure that as soon as I have the UUID, at least I can attempt a restoration.

Answer (score 0):

You can get his done by a simple command:

> ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid

this should work flawlessly, since `ls` is a core functionality.